# jquery align menu and logo not working in safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am having issues aligning my sites logo to the centre of the screen and having the menu appear on either side. from a recommendation that a friend gave me i am using a mixture of css, jQuery and html to accomplish this. This world great on firefox and chrome but the alignment is completely incorrect in safari. here is the code:

jQuery:

```
$('#logo').css('margin-left', '-'+($('#logo').width()/2)+'px');
$('.header .menu .container .left-side-menu').css('padding-right',($('#logo').width()/2)+60+'px');
$('.header .menu .container .right-side-menu').css('padding-left',($('#logo').width()/2)+60+'px');
```

HTML:

```
<h1><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><img id="logo" src="<?php echo     $logo['magethemes_zen_theme_logo']; ?>" title="<?php echo $name_bloginfo; ?>"     alt="<?php echo $name_bloginfo; ?> logo" /></a></h1>
```

CSS:

```
#logo {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;
z-index: 10;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; }
#logo:hover {
  top: -6px; }
  @media all and (max-width: 680px) {
    #logo:hover {
      top: 0; } }
#logo a {
  display: block; }
```

btw. i am using Wordpress for this site, so the menu is displayed using the standard Wordpress codex.

Here is what it looks like on chrome (working):

[image]

and here is what safari looks like (not working):
[image]